# Android Service or Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

My app is for tracking, have to send to php all I got. I have methods such as postData to php, my location listener class and getMyPhoneNumber. My question is what should I choose to develop that app? I have read Android Service and Broadcast Receiver documents and I still can't figure it out. Which one of them is more suitable?
PS, Thanks in advance

Comment: I have service in one class and on the other are the methods, How to activate them, I want everything to be invisible, so I think if i use extends Activity, they will become visible...?

Answer (score 1):

suitable depends upon requirment . 
if you want to receive particular broadcast or in other words want to do some operation on specific event like location change use broadcase Reciever while if you want something to happen consistently use srvice .

service will always run (in background) while BroadCastReceiver will receive related broadcast and run

Comment: But the idea is to track the location of the phone every 3,4 minutes and to send it to php and it should be in the background. I don't want it visible.

Comment: use alarmManager and setPending intent which will send update .schedule it for 3,4 minutes